# Auto-Escape dynamic strings in Powershell

Tags: powershell, escaping

I've got a string that will be dynamically generated from a 3rd party application

```
$somePath = "D:\some\path\name.of - my file [20_32_21].mp4"
```

I need to be able to verify this path in a function.

```
$somePath = "D:\some\path\name.of - my file [20_32_21].mp4"

Function ValidatePath{
    Param($path)
    if(Test-Path $path){
        Write-Host "Worked"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Didn't Work"
    }
}

ValidatePath $somePath 
# DIDN'T WORK
```

The problem is that it fails on the square brackets.

How can I automatically escape the square brackets in order to validate the file?

```
# Path needs to look like this
$somePath = "D:\some\path\name.of - my file ``[20_32_21``].mp4"
ValidatePath $somePath 
# WORKED!!!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use -LiteralPath instead of -Path; e.g.:

```
if ( test-path -literalpath $path ) {
  ....
}
```

Bill

Comment: Simple and beautiful. Some of the semantics of PS seem elusive until you actually see it. I didn't know about that bit.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using "test-path -literalpath $path" ?